# imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) allways null while bitmap not null

Tags: android, android-imageview, nullreferenceexception

i pass a String photo path to another activity, then i convert it to Uri (because photo path was converted from Uri), then i made the inputstream by uri, and made bitmap by that inputstream. bitmap is created and not null, but when i call `imageView.setImagebitmap(bitmap)`, system give error that:

> void android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference.

```
private void showImage(Uri mPath) {
    PhotoPath=mPath.toString();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mPath);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
        photo.setImageURI(mPath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

what problem i met, please help me ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ImageView itself is null. Resolving that problem will probably fix your error.